# Swift enum function for only a single case of the enum?

Tags: ios, swift, function, enums

I want to declare a function which I can only use for a single specific enum case.

For example I have CustomTextFieldTypes enum. This has the following cases and functions.

```
enum CustomTextFieldTypes {

    case CardType
    case CardNumber
    case CardExpiryDate
    case CardName
    case CCVNumber

    func inputCardNumber(cardNumber: String!, cardNumberTextField: XCUIElement?) {        
       cardNumberTextField?.typeText(cardNumber)
    }

    func inputCardCCVNumber(cardCCVNumber: String!, cardCCVNumberTextField: XCUIElement?) {        
       cardCCVNumberTextField?.typeText(cardCCVNumber)
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the `inputCardNumber(...)` function only for the     `CustomTextFieldTypes.CardNumber` case. I can do the following...

```
CustomTextFieldTypes.CardNumber.inputCardNumber(...)
```

But at the same time I can do this...

```
CustomTextFieldTypes.CardExpiryDate.inputCardNumber(...) or    
CustomTextFieldTypes.CardNumber.inputCardNumber(...)
```

I only want to call the `inputCardNumber(...)` function for the `CardNumber` case. Not from another case the enum itself. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT- Here's some background on what I'm doing. I was writing a UI test which would input text into text fields. I wanted to keep the input code away from my test file and I started "**Experimenting**" with enums and enum functions. I was wondering if I could have a function explicitly available for an enum case. Judging from the comments I cannot do this (I checked online but didn't get far). It's not a bad architecture or anything, I was just splitting up test code..

Thanks for everyone for replying.

Comment: What are you trying to do? And why use `XCUIElement`? They are for test only

Comment: Why put a function in an enum? What is the benefit of this?

Comment: You cannot make a function only available to one case of an enum. Any function in an enum is available to every case of the enum. From your small code snippet, it seems like you have an architecture problem and could probably come up with a better design to do what you want to do. We don't have enough information to give you any better advice.

Comment: Why are `inputCardNumber` and `inputCardCCVNumber` separate functions that have identical implementations? I suspect there's more to your problem than you're describing here. Agreed with @keithbhunter that you likely have a deeper design problem. Your types seem inside-out.

Comment: I've updated the question, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 15):

You can perform a switch on `self` in order to execute certain code for certain cases. Here's an example:

```
enum CustomTextFieldTypes {

    case cardType
    case cardNumber
    case cardExpiryDate
    case cardName
    case ccvNumber

    func inputCardNumber(cardNumber: String!, cardNumberTextField: XCUIElement?) {  
        switch self {
        case .cardNumber:
            cardNumberTextField?.typeText(cardNumber)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still adds a function for ALL cases, but it only does something for certain ones.

Splitting the enum in different ones and then adding protocol conformance would be a better approach.

Answer (score 9):

No need to use a switch when you only want to match a single case:

```
enum CustomTextFieldTypes {

  case cardType
  case cardNumber
  case cardExpiryDate
  case cardName
  case ccvNumber

  func inputCardNumber(cardNumber: String!, cardNumberTextField: XCUIElement?) {
    if case .cardNumber = self {
        cardNumberTextField?.typeText(cardNumber)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Dont know exactly why are XCUIElements needed but do something like this

```
//MARK: Declaration
enum CustomTextFieldTypes {
    case CardType(String)
    case CardNumber(String)
    case CardExpiryDate(String)
    case CardName(String)
    case CCVNumber(String)
}

//MARK: Definition
var cardNumber = CustomTextFieldTypes.CardNumber("123")
var cardExpiry = CustomTextFieldTypes.CardExpiryDate("10-10-2016")

//MARK: Usage
func useCard(type: CustomTextFieldTypes)
{
    switch type {
    case .CardNumber(let numberString):
          print(numberString)
    case .CardType(let cardtype):
          print(cardtype)
    case .CardExpiryDate(let expiryDate):
          print(expiryDate)
    case .CardName(let name):
          print(name)
    case .CCVNumber(let ccvnumber):
        print(ccvnumber)
    }

}

useCard(cardNumber)
useCard(cardExpiry)
```

If you really neeed XCUIElement then change `case CardType(String)` to `case CardType(String, XCUIElement)` and update all the other code as well